# How to show points on the axes neatly in LogLogPlot?

Tags: plotting

Plotting `f[x]` as below

```
 f[x_] = 4.4978`/x^2 - 1.9057/x + 1000 x + 10 x^2;
LogLogPlot[{(f[x])^(-1/2)}, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, 
 LabelStyle -> {16, FontFamily -> "Times"}, ImageSize -> 350]
```

leads to the following plot

[image]

How can one show the points on the horizontal axis in a non-congested way?

Answer (score 5):

```
scaledTicks = Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}];
scaledTicksNoLabels = Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{Log, Exp}];

llp = LogLogPlot[{(f[x])^(-1/2)}, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, 
   LabelStyle -> {16, FontFamily -> "Times"}, ImageSize -> 350];

llp2 = Show[llp, 
   FrameTicks -> 
   {{scaledTicks, scaledTicksNoLabels}, 
    {scaledTicks[##] /. {a_Real, n_, b___} :> {a, Rotate[n, -90 Degree], b} &,
     scaledTicksNoLabels}}];

Row[{llp, llp2}, Spacer[20]]
```

[image]

Comment: In the plot on the right, on the $x-$axis, why are the first and last numbers not rotated?  Is that a desired feature?

Comment: @mjw, updated with a fix.

Comment: Thank you!${}{}{}{}{}$